# How to compile python script to binary executable

Tags: python, compilation, executable

I need to convert a Python script to a Windows executable.

I have Python 2.6 installed to `python26`.

I have created one script and kept it in `C:\pythonscript`. Inside this folder there are two files

`Setup.py` and `oldlogs.py` (this file need coversion)

`setup.py` code is

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(console=['oldlogs.py'])
```

How can I convert oldlogs.py to an exe file?

Comment: see it's [tutorial](http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial)

Comment: For completeness, [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) is another tool that you can use for this (along with PyInstaller and py2exe, which other answers have already mentioned).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a Python script standalone executable to run without ANY dependency?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency)

Answer (score 80):

Or use [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) as an alternative to [py2exe](https://www.py2exe.org/). Here is a good [starting point](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html). PyInstaller also lets you create executables for linux and mac...

Here is how one could fairly easily use PyInstaller to solve the issue at hand:

```
pyinstaller oldlogs.py
```

From the tool's documentation:

> PyInstaller analyzes myscript.py and:
>
> - Writes myscript.spec in the same folder as the script.
> - Creates a folder build in the same folder as the script if it does not exist.
> - Writes some log files and working files in the build folder.
> - Creates a folder dist in the same folder as the script if it does not exist.
> - Writes the myscript executable folder in the dist folder.
>
> In the dist folder you find the bundled app you distribute to your users.

Comment: [cx_Freeze](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) is better, it supports even python 3.3.

Comment: Hey, this even works with [wine](http://winehq.org), at least up to version 3.4 of python, which supports Windows XP. Really great! I created a windows executable with **wine**, **python 3.4** and **pip-Win** (just follow the installation instructions on pyinstaller website) on my Fedora Linux machine.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, Both seem to be cross platform.. however, if I had to quickly judge which one to use just based on `GitHub` stars, `PyInstaller` has ~4000 stars, `cx_Freeze` has 200 stars. So `PyInstaller` seems to be more popular and probably has more edge cases covered.

_why do you think `cx_Freeze` is better than `PyInstaller`?_

Comment: Note that compared to PyInstaller, "cx_Freeze does not support building a single file exe, where all of the libraries for your application are embedded in one executable file." https://cx-freeze.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#single-file-executables

Answer (score 16):

I recommend [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/), a simple python script can be converted to an exe with the following commands:

```
utils/Makespec.py [--onefile] oldlogs.py
```

which creates a yourprogram.spec file which is a configuration for building the final exe. Next command builds the exe from the configuration file:

```
utils/Build.py oldlogs.spec
```

More can be found [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Answer (score 10):

Since other SO answers link to this question it's worth noting that there is another option now in [PyOxidizer](https://github.com/indygreg/PyOxidizer).

It's a rust utility which works in some of the same ways as pyinstaller, however has some additional features detailed [here](https://pyoxidizer.readthedocs.io/en/stable/comparisons.html#pyinstaller), to summarize the key ones:

- Single binary of all packages by default with the ability to do a zero-copy load of modules into memory, vs pyinstaller extracting them to a temporary directory when using `onefile` mode
- Ability to produce a static linked binary

(One other advantage of `pyoxidizer` is that it does not seem to suffer from the `GLIBC_X.XX not found` problem that can crop up with pyinstaller if you've created your binary on a system that has a glibc version newer than the target system).

Overall pyinstaller is much simpler to use than PyOxidizer, which often requires some complexity in the configuration file, and it's less Pythony since it's written in Rust and uses a configuration file format not very familiar in the Python world, but PyOxidizer does some more advanced stuff, especially if you are looking to produce single binaries (which is not pyinstaller's default).

Comment: I also recommend PyOxidizer, it is cross platform, zero-copy strategy and modern. See https://pyoxidizer.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pyoxidizer_comparisons.html for more details on comparisons with other tools.

Answer (score -2):

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['SCRIPT.py'],
             pathex=[
                 'folder path',
                 'C:\\Windows\\WinSxS\\x86_microsoft-windows-m..namespace-downlevel_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17134.1_none_50c6cb8431e7428f',
                 'C:\\Windows\\WinSxS\\x86_microsoft-windows-m..namespace-downlevel_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.17134.1_none_c4f50889467f081d'
             ],
             binaries=[(''C:\\Users\\chromedriver.exe'')],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='NAME OF YOUR EXE',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```