# How to Run a Program in Python.

Tags: python, py2exe

I am trying to make a script which would run an .exe file from my computer. I think I am using the wrong command. I tried all the other commands like `import os, os.startfile`, but they aren't working.

Here is my code:

```
loop=0
while loop==0:
    answer=raw_input("coded by: Narralol\n\n"
    "Pick a task:\n"
    "1) Start Minecraft.exe\n"
    "2) Start Minecraft_Server.jar\n"
    "3) Backup your server\n"
    "4) Copy the backup to your desktop\n"
    "5) Exit\n")
    if answer==1:
        execfile('D:\Games\Minecraft\Minecraft.exe')
    elif answer==2:
        execfile('D:\Games\Minecraft\Minecraft_server.jar')
    elif answer==5:
        loop=1
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/12339671/1240268

Comment: You can edit the title :). I added the tag py2exe which I assume you are using to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [os.system()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.system) like so (note: it is usually better to use `subprocess` for doing things like this):

```
answer = 0
while answer < 5:
    answer = int(raw_input("coded by: Narralol\n\n"
    "Pick a task:\n"
    "1) Start Minecraft.exe\n"
    "2) Start Minecraft_Server.jar\n"
    "3) Backup your server\n"
    "4) Copy the backup to your desktop\n"
    "5) Exit\n").strip())
    if answer == 1:
        os.system('D:\Games\Minecraft\Minecraft.exe')
    elif answer == 2:
        os.system('D:\Games\Minecraft\Minecraft_server.jar')
    elif answer == 5:
        break
```

Changed a few other minor things in the code like checking an int against another int (instead of string against an int), etc.

Comment: Yeah, thank you very much, it's working :) I think the problem was that the answer was recognised as a string rather then an int so it wasn't executing the file. It just kept going in loop without doing anything. Maybe that could be the mistake?

Comment: That is correct, i.e.: `x = "1"; y = 1; x != y; int(x) == y; x == str(y)`

Comment: Oooooh yes I understand now :). That makes perfect sense!

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`subprocess` module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) to run external commands:

```
import subprocess

    subprocess.call('D:\Games\Minecraft\Minecraft.exe')
```

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Even the `os.system` documentation points to `subprocess` as the preferable method; for one, the default argument handling method avoids shell injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: yeah I know ... but he is controlling the input and doesnt need the output ... so in this case I would say os.system would work fine...but subprocess is certainly the "right" way to do it