# Is it possible to freeze python code in to a single portable file

Tags: python, freeze

Is py2exe able to do this? I'm of course implying a single filename.exe without any dependency folders or other dlls.

Edit: compiling the files to .exe (py2exe) and packing dlls in to a setup file (with inno) is quite different, since there is an extraction involved.

Comment: For simple, light programs, i think so. Have you tried it?

Comment: There is wxPython involved; so my chances are pretty low, I guess. My previous attempts have always had a library.zip for .pyc modules and some dlls.

Comment: I used PyInstaller, maybe you can try that, It's easy to use.

Comment: cx_freeze, bbfreeze and PyInstaller all produce the same results.

Comment: Check out this this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339671/how-to-compile-python-script-to-binary-executable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Found it! (I overlooked it)*

**PyInstaller** could do the job like this:

```
C:\python pyintaller.py --onefile -w guiscript.py
```

(-w flag is the 'windowed' mode for hiding console)