# Is it possible to create a .exe file from a Qt Gui Application

Tags: python, qt

Is there a way to get this application as a ".exe" file. For example let's say I have a login application designed. Can I have it as a "Login.exe" file so that when I have it on my computer and double click on it, it would open up? I have the login.ui file and the login.py file. What would I need to create a .exe file of this application?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may find what you are looking for in a number of other discussions on SO:

[How can I create a directly-executable cross-platform GUI app using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2933/how-can-i-create-a-directly-executable-cross-platform-gui-app-using-python)

[How to compile python script to binary executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339671/how-to-compile-python-script-to-binary-executable)

and many others. Good luck!