# Making a Stand Alone Executable from a Python Project

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, exe

I have a big python program which contains a lot of python files, images, etc.

I tried to create an executable file of all the program, but it does not success.

I am using PyQt5, Tesorflow and many other classes.

I hope anyone can help to create an exe for my final univesity project.

Thank You a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339671/how-to-compile-python-script-to-binary-executable) with a sample. and here a nice [article](https://medium.com/dreamcatcher-its-blog/making-an-stand-alone-executable-from-a-python-script-using-pyinstaller-d1df9170e263).

basically, you get a tool like pyinstaller:

```
pyinstaller --onefile <your_script_name>.py
```

If you have more than 1 file, as you say in your answer then you can use compile all:

```
compileall.compile_dir(dir, maxlevels=10, ddir=None, force=False, rx=None, quiet=0, legacy=False, optimize=-1, workers=1)
```

as [shown here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/compileall.html)

Have a look at this [Git project](https://gist.github.com/diyan/1759391) that uses IronPython
and this [web page](https://dbaportal.eu/2009/12/21/ironpython-how-to-compile-exe/) that has a step by step for IronPython

Good luck

Comment: I tried this, but because I have a big project with a lot of py files and anothers file, it doesn't work.
I need somehow to add all my files to the executable file.

Comment: I am just not sure how to define the main execute py file in this way.
The dir includes all the files, how can I determine which one is the one to run?
Thanks.

Comment: make a .py file that would work as "main" and specify that 
#Build EXE
#gb=["/main:FredMain.py","FredSOAP.py","/target:exe","/out:Fred_Download_Tool"]

#pyc.Main(gb). have a look at the step by step