# How to have a executable file to run from Python

Tags: python, visual-studio, executable

In the Visual Studio we can easily write some codes, run and then compile the codes and finally have a unique executable file to run in Windows. I'm a beginner in Python and it seems we can easily write some codes and run as well. But I need to have a unique executable file that I can click on it and it performs the code in Windows. Is it possible to do such thing? I mean users don't need to see codes and by performing some steps run the program. They just click and run the application.

Comment: You can find answers to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339671/how-to-compile-python-script-to-binary-executable).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a Python script standalone executable to run without ANY dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency)