# Wondering how to use Python within Node.js / Electron

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, electron

I am working on an audio editing prototype. At the moment it is very simple, so it currently works as a Web App using JavaScript, HTML and CSS. This makes it possible to build as an Electron app, using Node.js to access the file system.

However, it makes heavy use of [a Python program called Gentle](https://github.com/lowerquality/gentle), particularly the file [align.py](https://github.com/lowerquality/gentle/blob/master/align.py). I was wondering if it was possible to integrate this program somehow, given how frequently it is used.

I am not familiar with Python, but I have tried to work out if this can be done. I have read about child_process, python-shell and zerorpc. However, if possible, I do not want to force the user to install Python along with all the dependencies required for Gentle, as it is a difficult process with lots of room for error.

This is where I have become stuck. Ultimately I am looking for a way to use Gentle in a way which gives the appearance of it being part of the functionality as a single self-contained program, rather than butchered on with duct tape.

I realize Gentle includes the option for a REST API and a Python server, but I am more interested in using Gentle offline for faster functionality. I am also too broke to afford hosting.

I realize I am kind of working backwards, as the front-end normally comes after the back-end. If it is easier I can try to rewrite the code base in Python or a lower-level language, but I am trying to avoid this if possible.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compile the Python program and include the resulting binary file into your Electron app and just run the binary via `child_process`. There are [several ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339671/how-to-compile-python-script-to-binary-executable) to create executables from Python programs.