# How to create binary of Python script

Tags: python, c++, angr

I am trying to use [angr](https://docs.angr.io/), a binary analysis toolkit for Python. I realized that I need a binary file to be able to load the project and start working on it.

How can I convert a python script or c++ program to a binary file? Is there a way achieve this?

Note: I believe the binary file is different than .exe file as I already tried **pycompile** which created .exe file.

Comment: Well, an exe is also a binary (for windows). Refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339671/how-to-compile-python-script-to-binary-executable.

Comment: Tools like `angr` are used when no source is available because all you have is a binary. They're kind of pointless when you *already have the source*. You don't need to reverse-engineer the code, you can just open it in a text editor.

Comment: Same goes for C++ if you already have the source. Just read it.