# Wrote Python code, now how to send to a friend?

Tags: python

I wrote a simple code that I would like to send to a friend. I dont want them to see the code. How do I get the program to work when opened?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compile python script to binary executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339671/how-to-compile-python-script-to-binary-executable)

Answer (score 0):

python is executed on runtime so the simplest way is to just send the source code

but there are options to get excutable files from python code

this was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570359/)