# Provide ability to run Python script

Tags: python, sql-server, powershell, powershell-remoting

I have a Python script which connects to SQL Server and exports the results in CSV using some Python libraries. I need to provide the ability for the team to run the Python script who does not have access to SQL Server. Is there a way I can wrap my Python into a shell and have them run that shell (executable) which will generate same CSV's?

I am open for suggestions.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Without providing the SQL instance itself, you cannot have a python script locally access the instance and process it, so I'm not entirely sure what you mean. You can [compile your python into a binary executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339671/how-to-compile-python-script-to-binary-executable), or you can try to [make a package via a virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html) that they can reproduce on their end if they have the database or another way of generating the database themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should deploy the sql service somewhere and use credentials on the python code to get the data and process it.
to protect the credentials you just have to deactivate read for this file and you are all good to go