# python read keyboard key bad performance

Tags: python, performance, optimization, input, keyboard

I'm working on a programm where I need a user input for selection while not focused on the console window. The method I want to use is with keyboard inputs on the numpad. I've found this library [Python keyboard lib](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard) to achieve this.
My problem here is that it takes very long time for python to register the key press and gives a feel of poor performance.
I need to know whether numpad 4 or numpad 6 is pressed for navigation. In the wiki of the lib was mentioned that you shouldn't use:

```
while True:
if keyboard.is_pressed('space'):
    print('space was pressed!')

This will use 100% of your CPU and print the message many times.
```

So, this is my code:

```
print("Choose Attacker or Defender operator:")
print("  Attacker    Defender")
att_state = False
def_state = False
while True:
    if keyboard.read_key() == "4":
        clear()
        print("->Attacker    Defender")
        def_state = False
        att_state = True
    if keyboard.read_key() == "6":
        clear()
        print("  Attacker  ->Defender")
        att_state = False
        def_state = True
    if keyboard.read_key() == "5" and att_state:
        clear()
        printAllOp(attackers)
        break
    if keyboard.read_key() == "5" and def_state:
        clear()
        printAllOp(defenders)
        break

selection = 0
while att_state:
    if keyboard.read_key() == "4":
        if selection > 0:
            selection -= 1
            clear()
            printAllOp(attackers, selection)
    if keyboard.read_key() == "6":
        if selection < 31:
            selection += 1
            clear()
            printAllOp(attackers, selection)
    if keyboard.read_key() == "2":
        if selection < 23:
            selection += 7
            clear()
            printAllOp(attackers, selection)
    if keyboard.read_key() == "8":
        if selection > 6:
            selection -= 7
            clear()
            printAllOp(attackers, selection)
    if keyboard.read_key() == "5":
        clear()
        searchOp(attackers, selection, att_source)
        att_state = False
        break
```

I've also realized that the performance is different when using if and elif that's why everything is written with ifs for now.

Answer (score 1):

Use read_event instead of read_key, it will block until there is an event.

edit: read_key here is launched multiple times, so every if condition will wait until a key is pressed or release. So instead of doing:
if read_key == 'a'
if read_key == 'b'
etc...
you can read only once like
key = keyboard.read_key()
and then compare your key:
if key == "4":
if key == "6":
etc...
if you want to get more informations on your input (key_up & key_down), you can use keyboard.read_event

Comment: I'm not super familiar with input like this in python, but this looks like a promising answer. A code example would be helpful. I think you are suggesting to somehow replace the whole while loop by using read_event, but I'm not sure.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can put microseconds or millisecond sleep for each while iteration, for 10 microseconds sleep,

```
import time

while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('space'):
        print('space was pressed!')
    time.sleep(seconds/100000.0)
```

This should reduce your CPU usage hence, it should increase the overall performance.

Even better, use keyboard hooks like [keyboard.on_press](https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard#keyboard.on_press). That's the right way of doing it.

Additionally, if it is ok for you to bind to an OS (Windows or particular version of Linux distribution), you can [compile your python as binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339671/how-to-compile-python-script-to-binary-executable), which is very simple to do using PyInstaller.

Comment: I don't think `keyboard.on_press` will work if the focus is not on the console window where Python is running. This is why I suggested `add_hotkey()` callbacks in my answer. I also don't think adding sleep to a busyloop will increase performance of detecting keystrokes by polling..?

Comment: It's not a CPU problem. Usage is under 1%.  It's something with the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using `keyboard.read_key()` at all, instead use `keyboard.add_hotkey()` to register callbacks which modify a global state.

Example:

```
att_state = False
def_state = False

def set_state(new_state):
    att_state = (new_state == 'att')
    def_state = not att_state
    # add code to update display

# Register callbacks for 4 and 6
keyboard.add_hotkey('4', lambda: set_state('att'))
keyboard.add_hotkey('6', lambda: set_state('def'))

# Process keystrokes until '5' is pressed
keyboard.wait(hotkey='5')
```

Note: I have never used this library and did not test this code (no Windows) so buyer beware :)