# Python multithreading without any server

Tags: python

My python code is just a library(group of files). For every API call I want to run 5 or more parallel calls to form the data. Is there any way i can write multithreading tasks without any server ?

Edit - The code is not deployed to any server. The zipped code is used by client. So in this case we dont the way how the client servers are configured.

Comment: `server` is more conceptual. What ever app you create to serve on an endpoint, that becomes a server :-). If your question was about using any available servers, mult-threading and servers does not relate directly.

Comment: "Server" is no more than a role of a device.

Comment: [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html)

Comment: I have edited it. multithreaded code requires additional memory storage. The code is used by client so I dnt know the storage or cpu or any other configuration

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you trying to execute python code directly in browser...

The most simple way is a JavasScript using, because it fully supported by Browser engine.
However browser don't know what is `python` and how to use it. Same thing happens if you try to run python script without python installed on your computer.

In other way it is possible to create [independent python binary executable file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339671/how-to-compile-python-script-to-binary-executable). That will allow to run python program at client side without python.

So it is possible to create `local server` executable and use it as `server` url to run operations. But user have to run this server binary manually, and it is looking not smart and pretty insecure.

In other way we have a nice technology [WebAssembly](https://webassembly.org) that allow us execute compiled code directly in browser. And looks like python also supported with [Pyodide](https://github.com/pyodide/pyodide)

[Here](https://testdriven.io/blog/python-webassembly/) is a `Hello World` created with Pyodide.

So looks like it is possible to run python without any server. But I guess here is still many limitations in comparison with backend-hosted python