# How to use Bazel to build ELF file for linux?

Tags: python, linux, bazel, elf

I'm new to Bazel, but I want to use Bazel to build my python codes to an ELF file (currently I'm building it to .par file). The purpose is to build an ELF file so that we can launch the program by double clicking the file, just like in windows double clicking an .exe file. Is there any way to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12339671/how-to-compile-python-script-to-binary-executable is about Windows, but most of the answers look like they'd work for Linux too.

Comment: I'm working on dedicated tools for ELF embedding. I built my own programming language and got it to load scripts embedded into the ELF itself. Python developers may be interested in this work. I recently published [an article](https://www.matheusmoreira.com/articles/self-contained-lone-lisp-applications) explaining the method, the Python interpreter developers could easily adapt it to their own project if they want to and it would probably be the ultimate solution to this problem for ELF targets. See also the [`patchelf` issue and patch](https://github.com/NixOS/patchelf/issues/533) I created.